# Typesetting Brauer trees in ${\LaTeX}$

Tags: representation-theory

Does anyone know of any packages that can be used to best typeset Brauer trees? An example of the sort of thing I'm looking for can be found for example on pages 119-123 of Alperin's book on local representation theory. I've tried various things but nothing I do seems to be able to match how it looks in this resource.

Comment: You'll probably want the LaTeX stackexchange for this sort of question. Anyway, I found this there. Hope it helps. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289268/how-do-i-concisely-typeset-propositional-proof-trees

Comment: I believe TikZ package - probably the most complex and powerful tool to create graphic elements in LaTeX - will do a job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try to draw a Brauer tree given on a page $121$. I used TikZ package. I hope you are satisfied with the result!

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[solidnode/.style={circle, fill=black!92, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2.5mm},hollownode/.style={circle, fill=white!84, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2.5mm}]
 \draw (0,0) node[hollownode,draw]{} -- node[below] {$s_2$} (1,1) node[solidnode,draw]{};
 \draw (0,2) node[hollownode,draw]{} -- node[above] {$s_1$} (1,1) node[solidnode,draw]{};
 \draw (1,1) node[solidnode,draw]{} -- node[above] {$s_3$} (2,1) node[hollownode,draw]{};
 \draw (2,1) node[hollownode,draw]{} -- node[above] {$s_4$} (3,1) node[hollownode,draw]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks awesome! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome @CoffeeBean and thanks for recommendation!